# The title is not at the bottom of the header

Tags: html, css

I would like the title to be at the bottom of the header, here is an example below

[image]

Except that, my problem is that the title is placed at the same height as the header and not at the bottom.

[image]

If I remove the header block, you can see the title.

[image]

I think it's a problem with my blocks? However, there is one solution, but I want to avoid doing  a `padding-top` on the title to get this result:

[image]

I made a reproduction [angular](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jw3bfk?file=src/styles.css).

Here is a reproduction [html/css](https://html-css-js.com/?html=%3C!doctype%20html%3E%0A%3Chtml%20lang=%22fr%22%3E%0A%0A%3Chead%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cmeta%20charset=%22utf-8%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3ETitre%20de%20la%20page%3C/title%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Clink%20rel=%22stylesheet%22%20href=%22style.css%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Clink%20rel=%22icon%22%20type=%22image/x-icon%22%20href=%22favicon.ico%22%20/%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Clink%20href=%22https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css%22%20rel=%22stylesheet%22%20/%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Clink%20rel=%22stylesheet%22%20href=%22https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css%22%20/%3E%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cscript%20src=%22script.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E%0A%3C/head%3E%0A%0A%3Cbody%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class=%22si$*$debar%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class=%22logo-details%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cspan%20class=%22logo_name%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ca%20href=%22https://zupimages.net/viewer.php?i$*$d=22/30/27uw.png%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3E%3Cimg%20src=%22https://zupimages.net/up/22/30/27uw.png%22%20alt=%22%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20/%3E%3C/a%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/span%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/div%3E%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cul%20class=%22nav-links%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ca%20href=%22#%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cspan%20class=%22links_name%22%20style=%22margin-left:%2020px;%22%3EAdministrateur%3C/span%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ci%20class=%22fa%20fa-chevron-down%22%3E%3C/i%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/a%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/li%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/ul%3E%0A%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%3C/div%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Csection%20class=%22home-section%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class=%22heading%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class=%22si$*$debar-button%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ci%20class=%22bx%20bx-menu%20si$*$debarBtn%22%3E%3C/i%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/div%3E%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class=%22menu-summary-container%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cspan%20class=%22user%22%3EUser:%20%3C/span%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cspan%20class=%22last-connection%22%3Elast%20connection:%20%3C/span%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/div%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/div%3E%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ch1%3EPortfolio%20page%3C/h1%3E%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%3C/section%3E%0A%0A%0A%0A%3C/body%3E%0A%0A%3C/html%3E&css=@import%20url(%27https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700$**$display=swap%27);%0A*%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20margin:%200;%0A%20%20%20%20padding:%200;%0A%20%20%20%20box-sizing:%20border-box;%0A%20%20%20%20font-family:%20%27Poppins%27,%20sans-serif;%0A%20%20%20%20list-style:%20none;%0A%20%20%20%20text-decoration:%20none;%0A%7D%0A%0A.si$*$debar%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20position:%20fixed;%0A%20%20%20%20height:%20100%25;%0A%20%20%20%20wi$*$dth:%20240px;%0A%20%20%20%20background:%20#0a2558;%0A%20%20%20%20transition:%20all%200.5s%20ease;%0A%7D%0A%0A.si$*$debar.active%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20wi$*$dth:%2060px;%0A%7D%0A%0A.si$*$debar%20.logo-details%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20height:%20100px;%0A%20%20%20%20display:%20flex;%0A%20%20%20%20align-items:%20center;%0A%20%20%20%20background-color:%20#fff;%0A%7D%0A%0A.si$*$debar%20.logo-details%20i%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20font-size:%2028px;%0A%20%20%20%20font-weight:%20500;%0A%20%20%20%20color:%20#fff;%0A%20%20%20%20min-wi$*$dth:%2060px;%0A%20%20%20%20text-align:%20center;%0A%7D%0A%0A.si$*$debar%20.logo-details%20.logo_name%20img%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20height:%20100px;%0A%20%20%20%20margin-left:%2018px;%0A%7D%0A%0A.si$*$debar%20.nav-links%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20margin-top:%2010px;%0A%7D%0A%0A.si$*$debar%20.nav-links%20li%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20position:%20relative;%0A%20%20%20%20list-style:%20none;%0A%7D%0A%0A.si$*$debar%20.nav-links%20li%20a%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20display:%20flex;%0A%20%20%20%20justify-content:%20start;%0A%20%20%20%20text-decoration:%20none;%0A%20%20%20%20transition:%20all%200.4s%20ease;%0A%20%20%20%20border-bottom:%201px%20soli$*$d%20#ccc;%0A%20%20%20%20padding:%2013px%200;%0A%7D%0A%0A.si$*$debar%20.nav-links%20li%20a.active%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20background:%20#081d45;%0A%7D%0A%0A.si$*$debar%20.nav-links%20li%20a:hover%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20background:%20#081d45;%0A%7D%0A%0A.si$*$debar%20.nav-links%20li%20i%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20min-wi$*$dth:%2060px;%0A%20%20%20%20text-align:%20center;%0A%20%20%20%20font-size:%2018px;%0A%20%20%20%20color:%20#fff;%0A%7D%0A%0A.si$*$debar%20.nav-links%20.item%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20text-transform:%20uppercase;%0A%7D%0A%0A.si$*$debar%20.nav-links%20li%20i.fa-chevron-down%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20right:%200;%0A%20%20%20%20position:%20absolute;%0A%7D%0A%0A.si$*$debar%20.nav-links%20li.active%20i.fa-chevron-down%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20transform:%20rotate(180deg);%0A%7D%0A%0A.si$*$debar%20.nav-links%20li.active%20i%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20color:%20white;%0A%7D%0A%0A.si$*$debar%20.nav-links%20li%20a%20.links_name%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20color:%20#fff;%0A%20%20%20%20font-size:%2015px;%0A%20%20%20%20font-weight:%20400;%0A%20%20%20%20white-space:%20nowrap;%0A%7D%0A%0A.home-section%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20position:%20relative;%0A%20%20%20%20background:%20#f5f5f5;%0A%20%20%20%20min-height:%20100vh;%0A%20%20%20%20wi$*$dth:%20calc(100%25%20-%20240px);%0A%20%20%20%20left:%20240px;%0A%20%20%20%20transition:%20all%200.5s%20ease;%0A%7D%0A%0A.home-section%20.heading%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20display:%20flex;%0A%20%20%20%20justify-content:%20space-between;%0A%20%20%20%20height:%20100px;%0A%20%20%20%20background:%20#fff;%0A%20%20%20%20align-items:%20center;%0A%20%20%20%20position:%20fixed;%0A%20%20%20%20wi$*$dth:%20calc(100%25%20-%20240px);%0A%20%20%20%20left:%20240px;%0A%20%20%20%20z-index:%20100;%0A%20%20%20%20padding:%200%2020px;%0A%20%20%20%20box-shadow:%200%201px%201px%20rgba(0,%200,%200,%200.1);%0A%20%20%20%20transition:%20all%200.5s%20ease;%0A%7D%0A%0A.home-section%20.heading%20.si$*$debar-button%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20display:%20flex;%0A%20%20%20%20align-items:%20center;%0A%20%20%20%20font-size:%2024px;%0A%20%20%20%20font-weight:%20500;%0A%7D%0A%0A.heading%20.si$*$debar-button%20i%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20font-size:%2035px;%0A%20%20%20%20margin-right:%2010px;%0A%7D%0A%0A.menu-summary-container%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20display:%20gri$*$d;%0A%20%20%20%20margin:%200%20auto;%0A%20%20%20%20text-align:%20center;%0A%20%20%20%20wi$*$dth:%20100%25;%0A%7D%0A%0A.menu-summary-container%20.user,%0A.menu-summary-container%20.last-connection%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20font-size:%2022px;%0A%7D&js=//%20JavaScript%0Adocument.getElementById(%27welcome%27).innerText%20+=%20%0A%22%20Editors%22;%0A).

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 240px;
  background: #0a2558;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sidebar.active {
  width: 60px;
}

.sidebar .logo-details {
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.sidebar .logo-details i {
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #fff;
  min-width: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}

.sidebar .logo-details .logo_name img {
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 18px;
}

.sidebar .nav-links {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li a {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 13px 0;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li a.active {
  background: #081d45;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li a:hover {
  background: #081d45;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li i {
  min-width: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
}

.sidebar .nav-links .item {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li i.fa-chevron-down {
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li.active i.fa-chevron-down {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.sidebar .nav-links li.active i {
  color: white;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li a .links_name {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.home-section {
  position: relative;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: calc(100% - 240px);
  left: 240px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.home-section .heading {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: calc(100% - 240px);
  left: 240px;
  z-index: 100;
  padding: 0 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.home-section .heading .sidebar-button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.heading .sidebar-button i {
  font-size: 35px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.menu-summary-container {
  display: grid;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu-summary-container .user,
.menu-summary-container .last-connection {
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Titre de la page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" />

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="logo-details">
      <span class="logo_name">
            <a href="https://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=22/30/27uw.png"
              ><img src="https://zupimages.net/up/22/30/27uw.png" alt=""
            /></a>
          </span>
    </div>

    <ul class="nav-links">
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span class="links_name" style="margin-left: 20px;">Administrateur</span>
          <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <section class="home-section">
    <div class="heading">
      <div class="sidebar-button">
        <i class="bx bx-menu sidebarBtn"></i>
      </div>

      <div class="menu-summary-container">
        <span class="user">User: </span>
        <span class="last-connection">last connection: </span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <h1>Portfolio page</h1>
  </section>
</body>
```

Thank you a lot for your help.

Comment: You're making life difficult by mixing flexbox with fixed position. Just use flexbox for the overall layout. Either use a primary row with sidebar and content as columns (each having its own header), or use a primary column with header and content as rows (with sidebar and page content as child columns). I fiddled with it a bit, but your layout is too complex for an easy conversion. It can be much simpler.

Comment: @isherwood, ah ok... Thank you for your explanation. I will change the code the next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *must* use a fixed position together with flexbox you can wrap the text in another div:

```html
    <div class="heading text">
      <h1>Portfolio page</h1>
    </div>
```

I then added some additional CSS:

```css
    .home-section .heading.text {
      height: calc(100% - 100px);
      align-items: start;
      top: 100px;
      padding-top: 10px;
      background: #eee;
    }
```

If you can follow the advice from @isherwood and don't mix fixed position and flexbox at all.

Example layouts using flexbox can be searched on the internet.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 240px;
  background: #0a2558;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sidebar.active {
  width: 60px;
}

.sidebar .logo-details {
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.sidebar .logo-details i {
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #fff;
  min-width: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}

.sidebar .logo-details .logo_name img {
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 18px;
}

.sidebar .nav-links {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li a {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 13px 0;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li a.active {
  background: #081d45;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li a:hover {
  background: #081d45;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li i {
  min-width: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
}

.sidebar .nav-links .item {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li i.fa-chevron-down {
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li.active i.fa-chevron-down {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.sidebar .nav-links li.active i {
  color: white;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li a .links_name {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.home-section {
  position: relative;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: calc(100% - 240px);
  left: 240px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.home-section .heading {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: calc(100% - 240px);
  left: 240px;
  z-index: 100;
  padding: 0 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.home-section .heading.text {
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
  align-items: start;
  top: 100px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  background: #eee;
}

.home-section .heading .sidebar-button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.heading .sidebar-button i {
  font-size: 35px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.menu-summary-container {
  display: grid;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu-summary-container .user,
.menu-summary-container .last-connection {
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Titre de la page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" />

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="logo-details">
      <span class="logo_name">
            <a href="https://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=22/30/27uw.png"
              ><img src="https://zupimages.net/up/22/30/27uw.png" alt=""
            /></a>
          </span>
    </div>

    <ul class="nav-links">
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span class="links_name" style="margin-left: 20px;">Administrateur</span>
          <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <section class="home-section">
    <div class="heading">
      <div class="sidebar-button">
        <i class="bx bx-menu sidebarBtn"></i>
      </div>

      <div class="menu-summary-container">
        <span class="user">User: </span>
        <span class="last-connection">last connection: </span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="heading text">
      <h1>Portfolio page</h1>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```